# How do you install Emacs on OS X from the console?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, emacs

I'm new to OS X and need to install Emacs 24.5 and 25.1 using the console to test a package using Travis continuous integration (http://travis-ci.org). My .travis.yml file looks like this (also testing with Linux) -

```
language: generic

# test on linux and osx (windows not available on travis ci yet)
# this os key also multiplies the build matrix (set below)
os:
    - linux
    - osx

# build matrix - test on different emacs versions
env:
  matrix:
    - EMACS=emacs24
    - EMACS=emacs25

install:
    - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME-$EMACS" == "linux-emacs24" ]]; then
        sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:cassou/emacs &&
        sudo apt-get update -qq &&
        sudo apt-get install -qq emacs24 emacs24-el;
      fi
    - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME-$EMACS" == "linux-emacs25" ]]; then
        sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-elisp/ppa &&
        sudo apt-get update -qq &&
        sudo apt-get -qq -f install &&
        sudo apt-get install -qq emacs-snapshot;
      fi
    - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME-$EMACS" == "osx-emacs24" ]]; then
          # install with homebrew - builds from source, took ~15mins
          # brew install emacs ;
          # even using the .dmg files takes ~6mins each
          wget https://emacsformacosx.com/emacs-builds/Emacs-24.5-universal.dmg &&
          hdiutil attach Emacs-24.5-universal.dmg &&
          sudo ln -s /Volumes/Emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs /usr/local/bin/emacs;
      fi
    - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME-$EMACS" == "osx-emacs25" ]]; then
          wget https://emacsformacosx.com/emacs-builds/Emacs-25.1-universal.dmg &&
          hdiutil attach Emacs-25.1-universal.dmg &&
          sudo ln -s /Volumes/Emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs /usr/local/bin/emacs;
      fi

script:
  make test
```

I initially got a syntax error with travis lint (http://lint.travis-ci.org/) - "syntax error: (): did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 30 column 3", which is pointing at the first if statement - that error turned out actually to be due to having comments inside the third if statement, so I moved them elsewhere.

So then I was able to install Emacs 25 with brew, as that is the current version it will build - but how would you install Emacs 24.5 with brew?

And is there a better way to install binaries on OS X than the .dmg files? They were faster than brew (6 minutes vs 15 minutes), but not as fast as apt install on Linux (~1 minute).

Thanks in advance for any pointers!